# og meta tag in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta-tags

I have a website on WordPress and I have declared `og` meta tag as mentioned below:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="fa_IR" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="معامله امن بازی های آنلاین - کافه گیم" />
<meta property="og:description" content="معامله امن بازیهای آنلاین" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://cofegame.ir/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="کافه گیم" />
```

but when I send my website link http://cofegame.ir in telegram, 
it shows this :

[image]

How can I fix this problem?
I use WordPress and Yoast SEO plugin and deactivated all plugins but the problem remains.

Thank You!

Comment: I don't get it. What is the problem? Can you tell us what do you expect? Or what is not working as you want?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing

```
<meta property="og:image" content="your_image_url_here" />
```

meta tag. This will have the image when you share your site url.

I usually put my og meta tags in header like this:

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="<?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>" />
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
?>
<meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo $url; ?>" />
<?php else:
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $screenshot_url = esc_url( $theme->get_screenshot() );
?>
<meta property="og:image"         content="<?php echo $screenshot_url; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

This way, if you are sharing an article, you'll have it's title, excerpt, link and thumbnail. If you don't set thumbnail, I put the theme screenshot. This can be customized of course, to show your custom image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank for your help i edit meta tag

 <meta property="og:locale" content="fa_IR" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="معامله امن بازی های آنلاین - کافه گیم" />
<meta property="og:description" content="معامله امن بازیهای آنلاین" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://cofegame.ir/" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="کافه گیم" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://cofegame.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Cofegame1.jpg" />
bu i have same problem

Comment: Your link to the image should be `http://www.cofegame.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Cofegame1.jpg`

Comment: thank's my image address have http but  in stackoverflow comment remove this

<meta property="og:image" content="http://cofegame.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Cofegame1.jpg" />